# PhpDoc. Parameterization of variables in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, variables, phpdoc

I heared Eclipse doesn't support parameterization of variables like this:

> `/**`
>
> `@var DBProxy`
>
> `*/`
>
> `$proxy;`

or

> `/**`
>
> `@var Uri`
>
> `*/`
>
> `$uri = Registry::get('uri');`
>
> `$uri->...`

But no completions available

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this :

```
/* @var $uri Uri  */
$uri = Registry::get('uri');
```

Basically, using :

```
/* @var $variableName VariableType */
```

should work.

Comment: Wooow! Thank you very much! :)
I tryed "Generte Element Comment" in Eclipse context menu, but it generates /* @var unknown_type */ without $variableName